# Why do I keep getting .class expected here? None of the usual problems are the culprit

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In all the other cases I could find, it was due to code not in a method or incorrect bracketing, however I have checked all these. My code is this;

```
import java.util.*; 
public class averages {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      //initializing
      double mean = 0;
      double deviation = 0;
      int i = 0;
      double dataset = new double[10];
      double sum = 0;
      double subdev = 0;
      double subsum = 0;
      double dev = 0;

      //getting the numbers
      for (i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
      {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a number");
         dataset[i] = input.nextDouble();
      }

      //calling the function to get 
      avgarray(dataset[]);
      System.out.println("Average is " + mean);
      devequasion(dataset[]);
      System.out.println("Deviation is " + subdev);
   }
   public static double avgarray(double[] arraydata)
   {
      sum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
      {
         sum += arraydata[i];
      }
      mean = sum / 10;
      return mean;
   }

   public static double devequasion(double[] devdata)
   {
      subsum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
      {
         subsum += devdata[i]*devdata[i];
      }
      dev = math.sqrt((sum - avgarray(devdata[]))/ 9.0);
      return dev;
   }
}
```

Everything looks correct, but the errors will not go away.

Comment: Your code has lots of errors in it - which ones specifically are you asking for help on? Or are you asking us to walk through and described each one (which would be too long a question for SO) ?

Comment: I don't know about .class expected, but you should be getting some complaint about your `double dataset = new double[10];`

Comment: You're coding all wrong as you shouldn't keep adding new code to bad code. If you're not using an IDE, you should compile frequently and correct all compiler errors ***before*** adding any more code.

Comment: @dogmatixed I havent gotten it to compile, I expected runtime problems. Also fixed the double, dont know how I missed it. Compiler didnt complain about it before or now.

Comment: math.sqrt() should be Math.sqrt() as its a static method of the Math class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few problems there, such as:

- Your defininition of dataset is incorrect. You create a array of doubles then try to assign that to a single double.
- You pass `dataset[]` rather than `dataset`.
- You have variables in `avgarray` and `devequasion` that are used but not declared (`mean`, `sum`, `subsum`, `i`, `dev`). The fact that these are declared in `main` is not relevant.
- Also, because they're only *used* in the methods, they're unnecessary in `main`, other that `i` of course).
- You don't import `java.util.Scanner` for the data input.
- The math package is `Math` with a capital `M`.

If you use an IDE like Eclipse, you will find it a lot easier to see and fix these problems. For beginners, that's a `${DEITY}-send`.

By all means pump your code into `javac` as a final step if you have to (headless builds, compatibility and so forth) but do your initial *development* with an IDE, you'll find it *much* faster.

Here's a version with all those syntactical problems rectified, and a few other minor tweaks, such as the removal of unnecessary variables:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testprog {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double[] dataset = new double[10];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
            dataset[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.println ("Average is " + avgarray (dataset));
        System.out.println ("Deviation is " + devequasion (dataset));
    }

    public static double avgarray (double[] arraydata) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
            sum += arraydata[i];
        return sum / 10;
    }

    public static double devequasion (double[] devdata) {
        double subsum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
            subsum += devdata[i] * devdata[i];
        return Math.sqrt ((subsum - avgarray (devdata)) / 9.0);
    }
}
```

*Don't* use this verbatim if it's homework, you would be foolish to assume your educators were not actively searching the web for plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

One the problems is

```
double dataset = new double[10];
```

should be

```
double[] dataset = new double[10];
```

Also

```
avgarray(dataset[]);
```

should be

```
avgarray(dataset);
```

Comment: Dont see how I missed that, thanks. However, compiler out put didnt change at all, so that didnt seem like it. Still showing .class expected

Comment: As well as the 3 times it's referenced needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a fix-my-code board, but there were too many errors for me to point out and tell you where and how to fix them. It was easier to just fix and post the whole code and add comments next to the huge amount of errors. You need to understand that variables have scope.

```
import java.util.*;

public class averages {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      //initializing
      double dataset[] = new double[10]; // FIXED (added [])

      //getting the numbers
      for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
      {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a number");
         dataset[i] = input.nextDouble();
      }

      //calling the function to get 
      avgarray(dataset); // FIXED (removed [])
      System.out.println("Average is " + avgarray(dataset)); // FIXED (calls avgarray)
      devequasion(dataset);
      System.out.println("Deviation is " + devequasion(dataset)); // FIXED (calls devequasion)
   }
   public static double avgarray(double[] arraydata)
   {
      double sum = 0; // FIXED (sum wasn't declared)
      for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++) // FIXED (i wasn't declared)
      {
         sum += arraydata[i];
      }
      double mean = sum / 10;
      return mean;
   }

   public static double devequasion(double[] devdata)
   {
      double subsum = 0; // FIXED (declared subsum)
      for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++) // FIXED (declared i)
      {
         subsum += devdata[i]*devdata[i];
      }
      // FIXED (removed [], declared dev, changed "sum" to "subsum", "math" to "Math")
      double dev = Math.sqrt((subsum - avgarray(devdata))/ 9.0);
      return dev;
   }
}
```

This will get it to compile, any broken logic is up to you.

**EDIT:** Sorry accidentally posted an incomplete version that was on my clipboard, fixed now.

**EDIT2:** It's also worth mentioning that you should use `array.length` in your for loops, rather than hard-coding in those values. Also for looping a specific amount of times, `i = 0; i`**`< 10`** can seem more clear that you want to iterate 10 times rather than `i <= 9`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 3 main issues that flow throughout your code:

1. You don't seem to have gotten your head around Java arrays
2. You don't seem to understand Java scoping rules
3. Coupled with the above, you're not handling function return values correctly

I'm not sure which one of those is the main problem you're asking about, but here goes...

*Some of thing is probably stuff you already know, but I'm starting at the beginning to make sure I don't skip over the bit you've missed*

An **array** is a fixed sized sequence of values. 
So `double[10]` is an array, with 10 values, each of type `double`
But `double` by itself is not an array, it's a single value of type `double`.

So this line:

```
double dataset = new double[10];
```

doesn't make sense. You're saying that the variable called `dataset` is a double, but then you try and put an array of doubles into that variable. That doesn't work.

Either you want dataset to be an array, or you want it to be a single value, but it can't be both.
Probably you want

```
double[] dataset = new double[10];
```

Later on, you have lines like these:

```
avgarray(dataset[]);
devequasion(dataset[]);
```

Those lines aren't valid Java code - it looks like you're trying to work around the problem of having declared `dataset` to be the wrong type, but youre work around isn't correct.

If you change the declaration of dataset to be a `double[]`, then you can simply have

```
avgarray(dataset);
devequasion(dataset);
```

and it will do what you want.

In Java, each variables has a **scope**. A scope defines how long a variable exists, and where it can be used.

So, as an example, you declare `sum` inside your `main` method. That means that this variable is scoped to exist only inside that method. You cannot use it (either to get the value, or to set the value) in another method - even if that other method is called from `main`. That means that inside your `avgarray` method, where you have

```
sum = 0;
```

that's wrong. You can't do that because sum doesn't exist inside this method.

You need to remove the declaration of `sum` from `main` (because you don't ever use it in main) and declare it in `avgarray` instead.

You have a few variables that need that treatment.

In some cases you're using the same variable in two different methods. To do that, you need to make the variable be a *member* of the class, rather than the method.

So, as an example, if you want two methods to use the `mean` variable, then it should be a member variable declared like this:

```
public class averages
{
  private static double mean = 0;
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    // ...
```

*But*, that's probably not the right way to do what you're trying to do.

If you look at your `avgarray` method, you see that it **returns** a value of type `double`

```
public static double/ avgarray(double[] arraydata)
```

and inside the method you correctly `return mean;`
But when you call it `avgarray(dataset);` you don't look at the return value.

What you want to do instead is have *2 variables called "mean"*. One inside `main` and one inside `avgarray`. Because of Java's scoping rules they are completely different variables that just happen to have the same name.

If you do that then you can write

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   // ....
   double mean = avgarray(dataset);
   // ....
}

public static double avgarray(double arraydata)
{
  // ...
  double mean = sum/10;
  return mean;
}
```

Given that some of the other answers have provided you with versions of your code that fix some of these issues, you should be able to piece it all together from my explanations and their fixed.

Best of luck!